# How to return columns of a select query in lower case irrespective of how they stored in DB? Is there any configuration change to achieve the same?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to retrieve the data using select statement. I have two different environments where the DB is hosted.

Environment 1 (Local): Windows 10, XAMPP (MariaDB)

Environment 2 (Dev) : Linux (Red Hat Enterprise), MySql

When I executed the query in my local machine, Db returns the results (Column Names) in their original form. But when I executed the same query in Linux environment, it returned the results (Column Names) in lower case.

[image]

The "1." is the columns returned in my local server and the "2." is the columns returned from Linux server.

So my question is, "Is there any server configuration that I need to change to make the behavior same across platforms?"

Ideally I need the behavior as like the Linux environment in my local system also.

**Note:** I have tried changing the "**lower_case_table_names**" variable without any success.

When I returned the "**lower_case_table_names**" variable in my local mysql it's already set to "**1**". What I'm missing here? What should I do to make the behavior of my local system like the Linux environment.

Comment: You can't control whether MySQL table names would be case sensitive, because that depends on the underlying OS (Windows or Linux).  Therefore, to avoid these problems, it would be a good idea to always use lower (or upper) case.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "lower_case_table_names"  to configure that ..  which is '0' by default in linux and '1' in windows .. And recommended to set this config only at the time of setting up server.

Check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html for more details

Comment: Thanks for replying. In windows by default it is 1. You cannot change it to 0 in windows.